# MultiChoiceModeListener over two ListViews

Tags: android, listview, tablet, fragment, android-listfragment

I'm working on a new Android application for tablets.

The view of the application is spitteld in two listFragments (left and right).

Is it possible to create a MultiChoiceModeListener which can select from both listFragments at the same moment.

In my solution its only possible to select elements from one of the listsFragments.

Example: I select a element from the left side with long pressing. When I try to click a element from the ride side, the elements on the left side are no longer enabled but the elements on the right.

Hope anyone can help
Thank you

Comment: intresting question. im implementing the listener as anon-inner-class and don't see where i should put a reference for a second fragment. Curious if anybody can handle this!